# Angular 4 - get innerHTML of ComponentRef in Dynamic Component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been trying to integrate dynamic `component`.

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

It's done except with a silly issue. Every time in my dynamic component an array of `[object object]` along with `HTML` elements.

In console, within `hostview` there is a `rootNodes` where `innerHTML` exists.

What is the way to get `innerHTML` within `rootNodes`?

Here is the `Angular` code -

```
    let factory = this.factoryResolver
        .resolveComponentFactory(TextFieldViewComponent);
    let component = factory
        .create(viewContainerRef.parentInjector);
    console.log(component);
    let componentView = viewContainerRef.insert(component.hostView);
```

Here `componentView` is the output HTML elements with `[object object]`

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the output of my dynamic component

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the template of dynamically added component -

```
<md-list-item>
<div class="formfield-wrapper">
    <div class="formfield-view">
        <label></label>
        <md-input-container>
            <input type="text" mdInput disabled placeholder="Textfield" value="">
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div class="formfield-options">
        <md-icon>settings</md-icon>
        <md-icon>remove</md-icon>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="textfield-label[]" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="textfield-placeholder[]" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="textfield-required[]" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="textfield-required-msg[]" value=""/>
</md-list-item>
```

In my console - I see the `object array` is being shown after my dynamic component `selector`. Like -

```
<ang-textfield>...HTML elements...</ang-textfield>[object object]
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the way you extract dom element from component factory, not sure if you still needed it, but for anyone else looking for it.

```
const domElem = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you are trying to pass HTML into your dynamically generated component? If so, you can use the `instance()` property to directly pass data into the component as if it was an input.

The component factory will return a [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef) which is a direct reference the component created. So you'll need to use the available methods and properties to access it.

For example:

```js
component.instance['innerHTML'] = "<div>Some HTML</div>";
```

Once injected into the component you should have access to that data as if it were an `@Input()`.

```js
@Input() innerHTML: string;
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to get HTML from my `componentView` object. Using `component.hostView` i get the view but with an additional text `[object object]` with HTML elements

Comment: I added an image of dynamic component output

Comment: Can you post the template for your dynamically generated component?

Comment: hey @user3384985 did u found the way to get html from componentRef ?